# Автозаполнение столбцов SQL Server

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Есть БД, между таблицами связи сделаны (PK-FK), как сделать, чтобы дочерняя таблицы по ключу получала данные, заполненные в родительский для неё столбец? Ну или хотя бы предлагалось выбрать (типа DropList) из существующих данных.

Comment: предлагалось выбрать где? в каком то приложении? ну так запрограммируйте в этом приложении выбор из списка



Comment: Нет, статичные данные заношу через management studoi в БД и приходится постоянно скакать между таблицами, смотреть чтобы вносимые значения совпадали с PK.

Comment: Managment Studio такими возможностями не располагает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй создать временную таблицу (declare @_TableName) с такими же полями как и в родительской (или дочерней), а потом объедини их при помощи оператора join по своим ключам, конечно, если они идентичны.

Answer (score 0):

смотреть default у полей и метод у FK ключей (там есть On DEFAULT)